# Java web application, public directory

Tags: jakarta-ee

I actually developing a Java web app. I create some file into my application and I want to let this file public for my user.

I realize that it is a bad idea to save them into WEB-INF so what is the good place to do this ?

And how can I get the path into my app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

anywhere in the war except WEB-INF should make it accesible to the uers.